# Have got usage question

Tags: grammar, tense, auxiliary-verbs, syntax

Consider this:

> We **have got** to go back 
>   *- Luke Skywalker in Star Wars V*

I don't think it is actually present perfect usage but certainly used like that syntactically. It is more like simple present usage. What do you guys think?

Comment: In my opinion, It's perfect in construction, but modal in meaning: it has the deontic modality meaning.

Comment: "Have got" has the same meaning of "have" in colloquial English, but is frowned upon in formal written English. See this previous question: [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/i-have-vs-i-have-got](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/i-have-vs-i-have-got)

Comment: @CanadianYankee This is not the case. "Have got + noun"  is different from "Have (got) to", which is a modal idiom.

Comment: @user178049 The context of that other question is possession rather than deontic modality, but I think Canadian Yankee's comment is correct in either case. "We have got to go back" and "We have to go back."

Comment: @Tashus how is it a possession? What is possessed here? "We have got to go back" should mean "we must go back".

Comment: @user178049 The *other* question is possession; the *current* question is not possession. However, Canadian Yankee's comment is true in either case. "I have got a brother" is equivalent to "I have a brother". "I have got to finish my work" is equivalent to "I have to finish my work".

Comment: @Tashus Sorry. I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

"Have got to [verb]" is an expression of present obligation. "[Have got](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Have_got)" is an auxiliary verb construction. The construction has the same meaning of the simpler and more standard "have to [verb]". In your example, "We have to go back" would have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It is a present perfect structure.   It uses the present-tense "has" and the participle "got".

I understand what "a present perfect structure" means.   It's a grammatical phrasing with identifiable parts.   It is a part of English syntax.   I have no idea what "a present perfect *usage*" might mean.

Certainly, I can express similar semantics using very different grammatical structures:

- We have got to go back.   *present tense, perfect aspect, active voice*
- We need to go back.   *present tense, indefinite aspect, active voice*
- We're obliged to go back.   *present tense, indefinite aspect, passive voice*

What I think is that **structure** and **meaning** are separate concepts.   They are related, and we often use one to help explain the other.   If they were identical and indistinguishable, we wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: I know they are different.but reason for my question is that if we remove has got with "have", meaning remains the same.this we can't do in other perfect sentences.

Comment: Oh!  That's because the meanings of *to get* and *to have* are usually related.  Once you get something, you have it.